# null variable QT

Tags: c++, qt

I cannot use the value of `a` outside of `loginButtonClicked()`

After clicking on push button the label doesn't get the value of `a`

How can I use the variable value outside `loginButtonclicked()`?

```
#include "menu.h"
#include "ui_menu.h"
#include "login.h"

Menu::Menu(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Menu)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
void Menu::loginButtonClicked(QString nomVal)
{
      a = nomVal;

}
Menu::~Menu()
{
    delete ui;
}


void Menu::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QString a;

    ui->label_2->setText(a);
}
```

Comment: `a` is a local variable of  `on_pushButton_2_clicked`. You are trying to use it on `loginButtonClicked`, which has no access to it. How could this ever compile?

Comment: Where is `a` declared? When you call `ui->label_2->setText(a);` in `on_pushButton_2_clicked` you are declaring another variable called `a` which will hide your previous `a` (assuming it's a global or member of `Menu`)

Comment: `a` declared private in menu.h 
What should i do so i can use the value that get `a` from `loginButtonClicked()` in `on_pushButton_2_clicked`

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It is a legit Q for a beginner!

Comment: Remove QString a; from on_pushButton_2_clicked

Comment: i'm a beginner as @LennartRolland said 

i have a slot that get value of `nomVal` from other form

`void receive::loginButtonClicked(int nomVal)
{
      qDebug() << nomVal;
      ui->spinBoxReceive->setValue(nomVal);
}`
but it doesn't change the value of the spinbox even if debug write the value getted from the other form

so i told my self to create a pushbutton who can `setValue()`of spinBox with the `nomVal` getted by `loginButtonClicked()`

unfortunately gives me that `nomVal = 0`

i want to know why `loginButtonClicked()` can't change spinBox value

how can i pass `nomVal` to `pushbutton`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you have to declare your variable either as a global one which means it will be outside any class, or as a class member which means it will be declared usually in the header file for your class. *NOTE: using global variables may be easier but it is not recommended practice.*

This is basic C++ and is not specific to Qt. You can read more about it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/).

Since you did not paste your header file it is a little hard to know how you have set this up, but as a quick hack here is an example using global variable:

```
#include "menu.h"
#include "ui_menu.h"
#include "login.h"

// Don't do this, make it a class member instead:
QString myGlobalVariable="";

Menu::Menu(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Menu)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
void Menu::loginButtonClicked(QString nomVal)
{
      myGlobalVariable = nomVal;

}
Menu::~Menu()
{
    delete ui;
}


void Menu::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    ui->label_2->setText(myGlobalVariable);
}
```